# Swift sometimes calls wrong method

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed strange behaviour during working with Swift projects. I can't explain it other than Swift sometimes calls wrong method. It is very rare and even adding blank lines to the code could lead that this error is gone.

Let me explain in screenshots what I mean, next I use CoreData example of SwiftDDP project that can be found on Github, but such issues I was able to see in my own projects.

Here we at `Todos.swift:74` where you can see breakpoint, I expect that next call should be `getId()` method of `MeteorClient` class because it was already instantiated:

[image: Screenshot 1]

After Step Into as you can see the `ping()` of the same instance is called:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The next two steps into lead to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception:

[image: Screenshot 3]

In my project I saw this issue fairly often before I stopped using singletons, so it could be related to Swift static memory usage or I don't understand something that is not surprising as I have little experience with multithreading and memory management.

My environment is:

- AppCode OC-145.184.11
- Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)
- iOS 9.2 SDK
- Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)

**NOTE**: Here I use AppCode but the same behavior I was able see in Xcode, and even more if the same issue that reproduces in Xcode could not reproduce in AppCode and vice versa.

Would be thankful if someone can explain this strange behaviour to me.

Thanks!

Comment: step1: create a new project. step2: create a minimal version of the issue. step3: post that code. step4: get awesome help! step5: profit!

Comment: Are you sure that your files were not changed after the building of project?

Comment: @RMenke as I wrote in question, even little changes could lead to that the issue is gone, even adding blank line. Actually I hoped maybe this is well known issue or behaviour.

Comment: @VladimirKravchenko if you mean changing source code that could move breakpoint to a not actual position then I'm sure.

Comment: This is not at all well known behaviour. That is why I asked for a minimal example.

Comment: I have the same behaviour since i upgraded to xcode 7.2.1, very very very annoying. Changing the method name, adding a print will fix it, smh. Happens randomly, and very hard to find some minimal code that reproduces it

Comment: @valR I'm glad to know that I'm not alone with that issue. You're right even a small changes such as renaming a method or adding a new line may cause the problem disappears.

Comment: Just doing a clean fixed it for me, but I have no idea when it will come up again, would a full coverage of tests help? can you run tests on a release build?

Comment: I just had the same effect. Cmd-Shift-K helped once, but then it again called the wrong function. I simply believe that Apple's Swift is crap. After one year pause I started over and see the same (plus this one) bugs as before.

Comment: This is serious. My suggestion would be: 1) reproduce the same thing on Xcode 7.3.1 2) record your screen with the issue happening 3) submit a bugreport on http://bugreport.apple.com 4) post this very issue on https://forums.developer.apple.com 5) keep this SO question updated if you find anything new about the issue

Comment: I see this issue about once a week. I just do a clean and rebuild. It is very frustrating.

Comment: Not sure what your code looks like entirely, but could it have something to do with the fact that in Swift, static and lazy properties are not atomic but globals are initialized atomically? That has contributed to at least one subtle problem for me.

Comment: I faced it sometimes just change your method placement and try it again.It'll be fixed.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of code into questions. It is much easier to see if you just copy and paste the code using the CMD-K to format it as code.

Comment: Try to reimplement the `getId()` method in your `Todos` Class. The reason the code calling the `ping()` method is in my opinion that the SwfitDDP-Framework is trying to stay connected with your sever. Is your server online?

Comment: I do not believe is magic and it is really difficult to understand without clean example. I believe the problem is not with Swift, most likely in combination of using Meteor itself and heartbeat object you have. As I see all operations are done in main thread, probably ping operatoion came with high priority in the main queue as hearbeat in Meteor is always checking the connection from time to time to react on this.

Comment: I have to say, 99.99999% chances are you have a programming error either in your code or in one of the libs you use. Having many Swift projects on going for two years already, I never have such issues.

Comment: To put insult to injury: I now have it that my code crashes randomly with strange exceptions and after a clean build it runs ok again. My suspicion is that Swift's cache is broken. Coming from compiler construction myself I never felt any real love for Swift. It turns out my feeling gets more grumpy over the time.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is a recurring problem for me. (Cleaning will fix it temporarily). It must be a Swift/Apple bug (not programming error) as a clean fixes the problem, and I can clearly see from the stack trace that the wrong functions are called. It only happens in the one file, and always when I try to call the one particular function.

Comment: I ran into the very same problem today too. The behavior weirdly always calls the same wrong function. The day before it just worked fine without any modifications. After I just rearranged the function position in my source code, the correct function was called again.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Called a method on an object in main thread, and the wrong method on that object was called, and stepping over again had EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Re-saving file after adding empty line fixed the problem. Looks like a Swift bug.

Comment: I've experienced this issue dozens of times over the past year on several Swift projects ranging from Swift 2.1-3.1 and Xcode 7.2-8.3.2. Re-arranging the location of my problematic function (ex. moving function from line 20 to line 40, or from line 40 to 20), but not the order in which the function is called, fixes the issue.

Comment: I just had a very similar problem that was consistent only on my physical iPhone. I "fixed" it by changing the location in code of the function that was erroneously being called. Biggest WTF moment I've had in probably 10 or 15 years.

Comment: Still happening in 2021,  
In my case it was an unused function that was being called, luckily the automated tests picked up that something was off.  I removed that unused function and now the correct one is being called.  Definitely a puzzling moment.

Answer (score 8):

This just happened on my team, using Swift 2.2. It's really incredibly strange. It's not a threading issue or an async problem, it was a very cut & dry use case. We called one instance method and another one above it got called. I deleted the method that was getting called, and then the one above THAT got called instead. Then I moved the method I was actually calling to a different location in the file, and it looked like multiple properties were getting called.

This is disturbing and worrisome, as now you feel you can't trust your code to run properly.

But we did "solve" it. We moved the method up to the code that was actually getting triggered, and after a little trial & error the right method got called. Not yet sure if this will manifest itself for other methods.

It'd be nice to be able to provide a simple project where this is happening, but it seems highly unlikely that it's possible, and I can't share a snap shot of my code base with Apple. It must be a perfect storm of something to cause a bug with Swift's run time.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, repeatedly. And my code base doesn't include any kind of hacks. I am working on a simple UI component and the UI only include this component and a button to invoke a method. 
When I call the "refresh" method on my UI component, different methods (like layoutSubviews) gets called :s

Comment: I got the same thing. My code was calling a completely different method in the same file. Except it was happening in a third party library my project was using. So I went inside the source code for the library and moved the intended method up to where the unintended method was located in the code, then build and ran it. Works as expected now. I honestly did not expect your answer to "solve" the issue. It just does't seem right, but I guess the nature of Swift is far more mysterious than anyone could have possibly imaged.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I think. Couldn't see that the *wrong* function was being called, but breakpoints on the function that *was* being called were never hit, and I couldn't step into the function from where it was being called. I added a new function (I called it `wtf`) with the same parameter list and implementation, and that one worked as expected, so it must have been a weird linking issue in the Swift compiler.

Update: super-cleaning appeared to work (see below), but it doesn't. Looks like I'm leaving my `wtf` function in.

<s>After *super*-cleaning the project, it looks like everything's working as expected again:</s>

- clean (cmd + shift + k)
- clean build dir (cmd + opt + shift + k)
- quit XCode
- delete derived data (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`)

FYI, in my case, the function I call is in a generic base class, called from a generic subclass, triggered by a specialized sub-sub-class. As we all know, the generics are still very buggy in the Swift compiler, so that's probably why I encountered this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple threads running? Maybe a network thread?

I thought I had this issue too but then it turned out my one thread was doing something and because the other thread crashed it stopped the other thread at a random point. I only noticed this thread so it seemed like it crashed at a random @IBAction function.

Comment: This isn't the case for me as the app doesn't always crash, it depends on which function that is incorrectly called, and what that function tries to do/access.

Answer (score 0):

When I switched to iPhone 6 simulator instead of iPhone 7, it seems to be working correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

Our app was rejected from review because of a mysterious crash. After debugging I found that it was having this same issue - but only for the Release scheme!

So I went through every setting in Build Settings one by one to see if switching it to that of another scheme would fix the issue: changing `ENABLE_TESTABILITY` to `true` fixed it......